# provide Get instance for Seq

Tags: scala, doobie

For instance, I have some entities with some params, and two database tables, representating this entities:

```
 entity                 param
╔════╦═════════╗       ╔═══════════╦════════╗
║ id ║ name    ║       ║ entity_id ║ value  ║
╠════╬═════════╣       ╠═══════════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║ "One"   ║       ║ 1         ║ "aaa"  ║
║ 2  ║ "Two"   ║       ║ 1         ║ "bbb"  ║
║ 3  ║ "Three" ║       ║ 1         ║ "ccc"  ║
╚════╩═════════╝       ╚═══════════╩════════╝
```

And a scala model:

```
case class Entity(id: Long, name: String, params: Seq[String])
```

And I want to retreive this data via `Doobie`, but I can't to do it directly to the `Entity` instance, cause `params` is a Seq of Strings, not just String:

```
val sql = sql"select e.id, e.name, p.value from entity e left join param p on e.id = p.entity_id"

sql.query[Entity].to[Seq]   //Error Cannot find or construct a Read instance for type: Entity
```

Is where any trick to provide `Get` instance for `Seq`?

If not, what is the way, `Doobie` offers to retrieve such data:

1. Write primitives instead of the `Entity` type:
   `sql.query[(Long, String, String)].to[Seq]` and compose this Seq of tuples to the `Entity` instance.
   Potentially not convenient, cause tables may have a lot of columns, what leads to copypaste this long tuple to the every new query.
2. Compose this primitives to anothes case classes:
   `case class EntityRow(id: Long, name: String)`
   `case class ParamRow(value: String)`
   `sql.query[(EntityRow, ParamRow)].to[Seq]` and compose to the `Entity` instance like in `1.`.
3. Like `2.`, but using `HNil`:
   `val entity = Long :: String :: HNil`
   `val param = String :: HNil`
   `sql.query[entity ++ param].to[Seq]` and compose to the `Entity` instance like in `1.`.
   I do not know any advantages or disadvantages of this way, as `shapeless` is a new thing to me.
4. Retrieve data with two separate queries:
   `val entities = sql"select id, name from entity".query[EntityRow].to[Seq]`
   `val params = sql"select value from param".query[ParamRow].to[Seq]`
   Probably not such perfomant as via single query.
5. Any another way?

Thanks.

Comment: If you pay attention, your query is returning a tuple `(Long, String, String)` which means that `sql.query[(Long, String, String)].to[Seq]` should work, now, you can do some processing group your result by id in order to get the `Seq[Entity]` that you need, if you like to do this with doobie, first you'll need to update you query to return an array on of values instead but analyze whether you really get benefits from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case class `Entity` expects `params` to be grouped together with id and name column as a list of strings,
whereas the sql query `select e.id, e.name, p.value from entity e left join param p on e.id = p.entity_id` will return you a rows containing id, name and value

```
joined entity
╔════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ id ║ name    ║ value  ║
╠════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║ "One"   ║ "aaa"  ║
║ 1  ║ "One"   ║ "bbb"  ║
║ 1  ║ "One"   ║ "ccc"  ║
║ 2  ║ "Two"   ║        ║
║ 3  ║ "Three" ║        ║
╚════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

This is not exactly what you want.
To achieve this we need to rewrite the sql query like below

```
val entities = sql"select e.id, e.name, GROUP_CONCAT(p.value SEPARATOR ',') as params from entity e left join param p on e.id = p.entity_id group by e.id, e.name".query[Entity]
```

Now you can map easily your sql query output to your case class.